# If $A_1, A_2, \ldots,A_n$ are independent events, prove that $P(A_1 \cup A_2 \cup \cdots A_n) = 1-\{1-P(A_1)\}{1-P(a_2)}\cdots\{1-P(A_n)\}$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I'm stuck on this problem and was hoping someone would give me a hint. I was thinking that $P(A_1 \cup A_2 \cup \cdots \cup A_n)$ is disjoint and so becomes $P(A_1)+ P(A_2)+ \cdots$ But I have no idea where to go from here.

Comment: Independent is not disjoint.  Events $E$ and $F$ are independent if they satisfy $P(E\cap F)=P(E)\cdot P(F)$.

Comment: What paw88789 said is very important to remember. In fact if two events are disjoint and both have positive probability of happening then they are not independent

Comment: Ayoshna - You've been using this site for a while. Please take some time to learn to typeset your mathematics properly. Your posts will be much more readable and therefore more people will be likely to read them. Here is a tutorial: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that by Demorgans Law
$$P\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^{n}A_{i}\right)=P\left(\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^{n}A_{i}^{c}\right)^{c}\right)$$
And since if $A_{i}$ and $A_{j}$ are independent then $A_{i}^c$ and $A_{j}^c$ are indpendent and $A^c=1-A$
$$=1-\left(P\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^{n}A_{i}^c\right)\right)=1-\prod_{i=1}^{n}(1-P(A_{i}))$$

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

(1): The union of some events means at least one of the events occurs.  So what is the complement of the union?

(2): If events are independent, so are their complements.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

1. If $A$ and $B$ are independent, then so are $\overline A$ and $\overline B$.
2. $\overline{A \cup B} = \overline A \cap \overline B$ (de Morgan's
   law)